# What's the best method for periodic tasks (a watcher thread)?

Tags: java, android, android-volley, android-threading

I need to execute periodic http requests. I use volley for the requests, but I don't want to overflow the queue.

Right now I've got a thread that enqueues the request and waits for 3 seconds.

```java
AtomicBoolean quitUsersWatcher = new AtomicBoolean(false);

class UsersWatcher extends Thread {
    final Context context;
    ActiveUsersWatcher(Context c) {
        context = c;
    }
    public void run() {
        while (!quitUsersWatcher.get()) {
            JsonArrayRequest usersRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, Config.ALL_USERS_URL, null,
                    this::getUsers,
                    Throwable::printStackTrace
            );

            try {
                RequestQueue queue = MySingleton.getInstance(context).getRequestQueue();
                queue.add(usersRequest);
                sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void getUsers(JSONArray jsonResult) {
        //some logic
    }
}
```

But I don't this that `sleep` is the best idea.
I thought about a variable that increases by 1 up to 64 or 128 and then enqueues the request.
Like this:

```java
int counter = 0;
while (!quitUsersWatcher.get()) {
    if(counter >= 128) {
        JsonArrayRequest usersRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, 
        Config.ALL_USERS_URL, null, 
        this::getUsers, 
        Throwable::printStackTrace);

        RequestQueue queue = MySingleton.getInstance(context).getRequestQueue();
        queue.add(usersRequest);
        counter = 0;
    }

    ++counter;        
}
```

But maybe there are some better tools to do something like this. I tried to search for a watcher, but I couldn't find anything useful.

How would you implement something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) or [Alarm Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) for calling the api repeatedly. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/background) documentation on how to handle background tasks in Android.

Comment: I've already seen these. It says the WorkManager is for tasks that work even when app restarts, I don't need it. The Alarm Manager is for alarm clocks or calendar events. And the documentation is more about kotlin, but I've only took a quick look. Imma read it again and see how it go

Comment: @Shout the AlarmManager is also used for repeatable task.

Comment: Aight, I'll use the WorkManager, thanks!